# Only returning rows where date is greatest and one addition critieria

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data

```
PET_REF XDATE       TYPE
123     01/01/2017  OBJ
123     01/01/2017  OBJ
123     01/01/2017  OBJ
123     02/01/2017  LVE
456     01/01/2017  OBJ
456     01/01/2017  LVE
456     02/01/2017  OBJ
```

Is it possible to only return rows for PET_REF where the latest (by XDATE) TYPE is not LVE

So, for the data above, the output should be

```
PET_REF XDATE       TYPE
456     01/01/2017  OBJ
456     01/01/2017  LVE
456     02/01/2017  OBJ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions059.htm#SQLRF00642) analytic function

```
Select * from 
(
select PET_REF, XDATE, TYPE, First_Value(TYPE)over(Partition by PET_REF order by XDATE desc) as Latest_Type
from yourtable 
)a
Where Latest_Type <> 'LVE'
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b29efa/3)

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is to try putting them in a subquery.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE c1 IN (
             SELECT c1 
             FROM t
             WHERE (c1,c2) IN (SELECT c1, MAX(c2) 
                               FROM t 
                               GROUP BY 1)
             AND c3 <> 'LVE');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (pet_ref, xdate, type) as
  2    (select 123, date '2017-01-01', 'obj' from dual union all
  3     select 123, date '2017-01-01', 'obj' from dual union all
  4     select 123, date '2017-01-01', 'obj' from dual union all
  5     select 123, date '2017-01-02', 'lve' from dual union all  --
  6     select 456, date '2017-01-01', 'obj' from dual union all
  7     select 456, date '2017-01-01', 'lve' from dual union all  --
  8     select 456, date '2017-01-02', 'obj' from dual
  9    ),
 10  inter as
 11    (select pet_ref, type,
 12            rank() over (partition by pet_ref order by xdate desc) rnk
 13     from test
 14    )
 15  select * from test t
 16  where t.pet_ref not in (select i.pet_ref from inter i
 17                          where i.rnk = 1
 18                            and i.type = 'lve');

   PET_REF XDATE      TYP
---------- ---------- ---
       456 02/01/2017 obj
       456 01/01/2017 lve
       456 01/01/2017 obj

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to do this just by using order by :

```
SELECT *
FROM datatable
WHERE PET_REF LIKE (SELECT MAX(PET_REF) FROM datatable)
ORDER BY XDATE ASC, TYPE DESC;
```

Try the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b23923/4)